# Use drop down to show/hide div

Tags: jquery

I am using a drop down to show/hide divs based on the selected option. 
The show/hide is working however I need to hide only divs that are related to each individual drop-down rather than each time hiding all divs on the page.

How can I select only the divs related to each individual drop-down?

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/fj63g/7/

```
<select id="dropDown">
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option value="div1">Show Div 1</option>
    <option value="div2">Show Div 2</option>
</select>

<div  id="div1" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 1</div>
<div  id="div2" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 2</div>

<hr />

<select id="dropDown2">
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option value="div3">Show Div 3</option>
    <option value="div4">Show Div 4</option>
</select>

<div  id="div3" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 3</div>
<div  id="div4" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 4</div>


$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

$('#dropDown').change(function(){

    $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
    $('#' + this.value).show();

});

$('#dropDown2').change(function(){

    $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
    $('#' + this.value).show();

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
$('#dropDown').change(function(){
   $(this).find("option").each(function(){
      $('#' + this.value).hide();
    });
    $('#' + this.value).show();

});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/fj63g/8/

Comment: and `#dropDown` can be changed to a class

Comment: nice and using a class instead of an ID makes it more portable!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

$('#dropDown, #dropDown2').change(function(){

    $(this).find('option').each(function(){
        $('#'+$(this).val()).hide();
    });

    $('#' + this.value).show();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3aRxW/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about changing classes of the each set of divs to be unique?
like:

```
<select id="dropDown">
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option value="div1">Show Div 1</option>
    <option value="div2">Show Div 2</option>
</select>

<div  id="div1" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 1</div>
<div  id="div2" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 2</div>

<hr />

<select id="dropDown2">
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option value="div3">Show Div 3</option>
    <option value="div4">Show Div 4</option>
</select>

<div  id="div3" class="drop-down-show-hide2">div 3</div>
<div  id="div4" class="drop-down-show-hide2">div 4</div>


$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

$('#dropDown').change(function(){

    $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
    $('#' + this.value).show();

});

$('#dropDown2').change(function(){

    $('.drop-down-show-hide2').hide();
    $('#' + this.value).show();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dropdown specific class groups:

```
<div  id="div1" class="dd_group1">div 1</div>
<div  id="div2" class="dd_group1">div 2</div>

<div  id="div3" class="dd_group1">div 3</div>
<div  id="div4" class="dd_group1">div 4</div>

$('#dropDown').change(function(){

    $('.dd_group1').hide();
    $('#' + this.value).show();

});

$('#dropDown2').change(function(){

    $('.dd_group2').hide();
    $('#' + this.value).show();

});
```